# How to save .NET Gridview row order to database after reordering using JQuery Sortable

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a database table that contains two fields, `ColumnName` and `SortOrder`.

I am using a gridview to display the ColumnName field on a page of a C# .NET web application.

I would like the user to be able reorder the rows by dragging and dropping the gridview rows, and then save this new order to the database by inserting the new row number into the SortOrder field in the DB table.

I have managed to get the drag and drop feature to work using `JQueryUI Sortable`. But I am struggling to get the new order of the rows server side so I can get it into the database.

**Gridview Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_ColumnNames" runat="server" CssClass="sortable">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" HeaderText="ColumnName" SortExpression="ColumnName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**JQuery**

```
    $(function () {

        $(".sortable").sortable({
            items: "tr:not(tr:first-child)",
            axis: "y"
        }).disableSelection();

    });
```

As a test to see if I can get the new row order clientside i wrote the C# code below but this just outputs the original row order.

```
    protected void BTN_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string orderTest = "";

        foreach(GridViewRow row in GV_FlatFileColumnSetting.Rows)
        {
            orderTest += row.Cells[0].Text;
        }

        Response.Write(orderTest);

    }
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can get the row order from client side to server side so I can run an SQL Command to insert the new order into a DB?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery sortable as an update event that gets triggered every time the you drop an element. It also has a toArray method which returns an array of the ids of the elements in the order which they currently appear.
Putting this with AJAX you can do something like this to call server side code.
This passes the array of ids as a json string that will need to be decoded server side.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    items: "tr:not(tr:first-child)",
    axis: "y",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var sortedIDs = $(event.target).sortableGrid( "toArray" );
      $.ajax({
        url: your url,
        data: JSON.stringify(sortedIDs)
      });
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Sorry I don't know .NET so I cant help you server side but hope this helps.